# How to create a 'rising' or 'What's hot' query in Mysql and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a filter to show certain records that are considered 'trending'. So the idea is to select records that are voted heavily upon but not list them in descending order from most voted to least voted. This is so a user can browse and have a chance to see all links, not just the ones that are at the top. What do you recommend would be the best way to do this? I'm lost as to how I would create a random assortment of trending links, but not have them repeat as a user goes from page to page. Any suggestions? Let me know if any of this is unclear, thanks!

Comment: first - define what you think would be a good sort order.  this is the real meat of your application - then you can get help with some sql.

Comment: What do you mean by sort order?

Answer (score 3):

This response assumes you are tracking up votes in a child table on a per row basis for each vote, rather than just +1'ing a counter on the specific item.

Determine the time frame you care about the trending topics. Maybe 1 hour would be good?

Then run a query to determine which item has the highest number of votes in the last hour. Order by this count and you will have a continually updating most upvoted list of items.

```
SELECT items.name, item_votes.item_count FROM items
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT item_id, COUNT(item_id) AS item_count
    FROM item_votes
    WHERE date >= dateAdd(hh, -1, getDate()) AND 
          ## only count upvotes, not downvotes
          item_vote > 0
    group by item_id
) AS item_votes ON item_votes.item_id = items.item_id

ORDER BY item_votes.item_count DESC
```

Comment: I'll admit that I don't understand this query completely but what I'm looking for is more randomness in their, so it will be showing voted up topics, but not list them in exact order. So basically find the 10% highest voted up and display that over 5 pages randomly going from a general high vote to a low vote. But without repeating results.

Answer (score 1):

You're mentioning that you don't want to repeat items over several pages which means that you can't get random ordering *per request*. You'll instead need to retrieve the items, order them, and persist them in either a server-wide or session-specific cache.

A server-wide cache would need to be updated every once in a while, a time interval you'll need to define. Users switching page when this update occurs will see their items scrambled.

A session-specific cache would maintain the items as long as the user browses your website, which means that the items would be outdated if your users never leave. Once again, you'll need to determine a time interval to enforce updates.

I'm thinking that you need a versioned list. You could do the server-wide cache solution, and give it an version (date, integer, anything). You need pass this version around when browsing the latest trends, and the user will keep viewing the same list. Clicking on the Trends menu link will send them to the browsing pages without version information, which should grab the latest from your cache. You then keep this as long as the user is browsing these pages.

I can't get into sql statements, not because they are hard, but we don't know your database structure. Do you keep track of individual votes in a separate table? Are they just aggregated into a single column?

Comment: I have a table to keep track of every post a user has voted on, my only question about a server wide cache what happens if you have thousands of posts? Do you just run the job regardless of how many items you have to sort? And how can you save the organization in a table? (Sorry if this is to many questions, just trying to learn :) )

Comment: It's up to the database to retrieve the matches, you'll need proper indexes setup. The ordering done in your code would only be applied to the small subset of returned posts from your database. A thousand posts returned from the database is such a small amount that you should be able to order it without worrying about speed. You can then cache the result, either as a list of post identifiers, or rendered html, in-memory to show users when requested. What type of organization are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a new column to record how many views it has? Then update it every time someone views it and order by threads with the largest number of views.

Comment: Ya, the idea is to not show go in order from top to bottom but kind of randomly but from a high to low, does that make sense? So the first page show have views any where from 800-900 and the next anywhere from 700-800, see?

Comment: use array_rand(). Put the rows from 800-900 into a php array and get array_rand() to randomly sort them. These rows will go at the top, using the order from array_rand(). Repeat this for each range.

Comment: Sure,  but if I only want to display 25 results per page, and I don't want to repeat results but I want to show them all what do I do?

Comment: Use LIMIT with WHERE. Ex: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE views > 800 LIMIT 0, 30` LIMIT determines how many rows to show you, this way there is no repeats. LIMIT is in the following format: startrow, howmanyresults

Comment: That would randomize the results on one page wouldn't it? So one page I would get the top 1 to 30, it would be random on the page but what if I want some that aren't in that range? Like I want to show all the links, in a general descending order with no repeating you see? So the overall it would be a descending in views but it would be randomly so through out. The first page would be the highest 10 percent, second page highest 20 percent etc.

Comment: For that, I have no idea, sorry. This is sounding quite complicated. It sort-of sounds like you are trying to create a forum. If you are, one thing I can suggest is MyBB. It is wonderful forum software for PHP and MySQL